# How to make Roku update instantly?

Tags: xml, roku, brightscript

I recently installed Roku and setup a channel using the example videoplayer. My xml files are stored on my server, but for some reason when I update them, the channel doesn't update right away, it takes quite a while, like hours. I don't know if it's caching or storing the data it retrieved, but I want it to update instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any caching being done in the Roku app, I'm wondering if perhaps your web server is doing it. I'd try configuring your web server to not cache *.xml files or maybe edit the source files and add a timestamp string to the URLs so that each hit is unique:

```
datetime = CreateObject("roDateTime")
conn.UrlPrefix = "http://your.server.com/path/to/xml"
conn.UrlCategoryFeed = conn.UrlPrefix + "/categories.xml?t=" + datetime.asSeconds()
```

Comment: I ended up changing it to .php files that loaded the roku, it appears to be working now.